# How to rebuild RAID1 with missing drive on CERC?

Tags: raid1, dell-perc

I have a CERC/4i on a Dell 750 with two SATA drives. Due to a failing cooling system one of the disks stopped working. This has occurred twice before, so I am fairly confident the disk is not (fatally) damaged. Previously, array rebuilding has been triggered by the following set of afacli commands:

```
AFA0> disk remove dead_partitions 0
AFA0> controller rescan
```

However, this time it failed to do the trick. I rebooted the box in the hope that the BIOS interface would have something, but nothing obvious. The current state of the RAID1 set is as follows:

```
AFA0> container list /full
Executing: container list /full=TRUE
Num          Total  Oth Chunk          Scsi   Partition                                      Creation        System
Label Type   Size   Ctr Size   Usage   B:ID:L Offset:Size   State   RO Lk Task    Done%  Ent Date   Time      Files
----- ------ ------ --- ------ ------- ------ ------------- ------- -- -- ------- ------ --- ------ -------- ------
 0    Mirror  465GB            Valid   0:00:0 64.0KB: 465GB UnProt                        0  032511 17:55:06
 /dev/sda             root               --- Missing ---

AFA0> disk list /full
Executing: disk list /full=TRUE

B:ID:L  Device Type     Removable media  Vendor-ID Product-ID        Rev   Blocks    Bytes/Block Usage            Shared Rate
------  --------------  ---------------  --------- ----------------  ----- --------- ----------- ---------------- ------ ----
0:00:0   Disk            N                WDC       WD5000AAKS-00V0A  05.0  976773168 512         Initialized      NO     132 
0:01:0   Disk            N                WDC       WD5000AAKS-22V1A  05.0  976773168 512         Initialized      NO     132
```

I tried to add 0:01:0 as a spare to the set using `container set failover 0 (0,1,0)` but this seems to have forced the volume into readonly mode and blocked any attempts to use afacli on the controller. After waiting 10 mins or so, I rebooted. State remained as above.

So no my question is: how do I convince the missing drive to re-join the mirror set?

If it helps:

```
Component Revisions
-------------------
                CLI: 2.7-1 (Build #4944)
                API: 2.7-1 (Build #4944)
    Miniport Driver: 1.1-5 (Build #2461)
Controller Software: 4.1-0 (Build #7401)
    Controller BIOS: 4.1-0 (Build #7401)
Controller Firmware: (Build #7401)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is:

```
container reconfigure /mirror 0 (0,1,0)
```

which informs the container to include disk 0:01:0 in the mirror set.

Comment: Good on you for coming back and answering your own question :)